# how to configure refine framework to present the url in a sub directory

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frameworks, refinejs

I have a project in refine (https://refine.dev) which is installed in a sub directory (eg: http.site.com/subfolder).

However, when accessing the site, the url assembled by refine is (http.site.com/login).

How do I make refine accept the subfolder and show the url as follows (http.site.com/subfolder/login)?

I looked in the framework documentation for a resolution to the problem, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

refine provides its features with react context API. It means deploying refine applications has no difference from any other react application.